# jqgrid showLink not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have formatters working for dates and numbers.  My formatter for a link is only working half-way for some reason.  All I get in my grid are links like this:

```
?id=1
```

Where the baseLinkUrl setting is not being used (or included) in the URL.

Here's my JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $("#d5d02a55-ba5e-46f2-a64a-05fd7870b273_list")
        .jqGrid({
        url: '/jqgrid2/getDataJson',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
        colModel: [{
                "name": "invid",
                "index": "invid",
                "width": 55,
                "formatter": "showlink",
                "formatteroptions": {
                    "baseLinkUrl": "jsp/samplePage.jsp",
                    "target": "_blank",
                    "idName": "invid"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "invdate",
                "index": "invdate",
                "width": 90,
                "formatter": "date",
                "formatteroptions": {
                    "srcformat": "yyyy-MM-dd",
                    "newformat": "MM/dd/yyyy"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "amount",
                "index": "amount",
                "width": 80,
                "align": "RIGHT",
                "formatter": "number",
                "formatteroptions": {
                    "decimalPlaces": 2
                }
            }, {
                "name": "tax",
                "index": "tax",
                "width": 80,
                "align": "RIGHT",
                "formatter": "number",
                "formatteroptions": {
                    "decimalPlaces": 2
                }
            }, {
                "name": "total",
                "index": "total",
                "width": 80,
                "align": "RIGHT",
                "formatter": "number",
                "formatteroptions": {
                    "decimalPlaces": 2
                }
            }, {
                "name": "note",
                "index": "note",
                "width": 150,
                "sortable": false
            }
        ],
        pager: '#d5d02a55-ba5e-46f2-a64a-05fd7870b273_pager',
        rowNum: 5,
        rowList: [5, 10, 25, 50],
        sortname: 'invid',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true,
        multiselect: false,
        gridview: true,
        caption: '',
        height: 'auto',
        jsonReader: {
            root: 'data',
            page: 'currentPage',
            total: 'totalPages',
            records: 'totalRecords',
            repeatitems: false,
            id: 'id'
        }
    });
});
```

And my data:

```
{ "currentPage" : "1",
  "data" : [ { "amount" : 1000.0,
        "invdate" : "2013-04-01 00:00:00",
        "invid" : 1,
        "note" : "No notes",
        "tax" : 60.0,
        "total" : 1060.0
      },
      { "amount" : 200.0,
        "invdate" : "2013-04-02 00:00:00",
        "invid" : 2,
        "note" : "",
        "tax" : 12.0,
        "total" : 212.0
      },
      { "amount" : 500.0,
        "invdate" : "2013-04-03 00:00:00",
        "invid" : 3,
        "note" : "",
        "tax" : 30.0,
        "total" : 530.0
      },
      { "amount" : 400.0,
        "invdate" : "2013-04-03 00:00:00",
        "invid" : 4,
        "note" : "Some notes",
        "tax" : 24.0,
        "total" : 424.0
      },
      { "amount" : 200.0,
        "invdate" : "2013-04-04 00:00:00",
        "invid" : 5,
        "note" : "",
        "tax" : 12.0,
        "total" : 2012.0
      }
    ],
  "limitRows" : "5",
  "totalPages" : "3",
  "totalRows" : "11"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The data which returns the server don't contain `"id"` property. If `invid` column play the role of `id` in your grid you should first change `id: 'id'` in `jsonReader` to `id: 'invid'` and seconds (in general it's an alternative, but I recommend to use both) to add `key: true` property to the definition of `invid` column.

The next important problem: you use `formatteroptions` instead of `formatoptions`. So the most settings which you use will be ignored now.

One more problem: you use wrong values for `formatoptions` of `formatter: "date"`. You need provide jqGrid the data in PHP format instead of more common described for example [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate). If you would open `grid.locale-en.js` (see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js#L108-L157)) you would find some examples of usage dates and some links which could be helpful you.

Comment: I corrected my misspelling for formatoptions, changed the date formats and all appears to be working.  Great!  I didn't make the change to the jsonReader for the id, and the URLs are being rendered OK.  I wonder why that is?

Comment: @MichaelSobczak: Do you included `key: true` property? Do you verified that you have correct ids on the second page? If no ids are found in the grid then the values 1, 2, 3,... (like your ids from the first page) will be used per default.

Comment: My sample data had IDs of 1, 2, 3, so my test wasn't valid.  Let me try adding the "key" property and also adding a row with an ID that is a few items after the last one currently in the table, to be sure things are working OK.  Thanks for the tip!